# MiniExcel - How to use Dynamic columns in combination with a Custom template?

Tags: c#, .net, aspnetzero, excel-template

I'm using MiniExcel in a .NET (ASP.NET Zero) Project to generate Excel files for my frontend Tables.

The Users can change which columns are shown and in what order for each Table, so I needed to use the [Dynamic IEnumerable](https://github.com/mini-software/MiniExcel/blob/master/README.md#2-ienumerableidictionarystring-object) approach, and it is working perfectly. I can set up the dictionary with the User's selected columns, in order, using this approach.

The problem is that now I need to include some custom fields above the Table in the Excel file. It would be like an extra "Header" showing a Report name and filter Details (like the Date when the file was Generated, and some of the filters that were used...). I've read through the documentation here: [https://github.com/mini-software/MiniExcel/blob/master/README.md](https://github.com/mini-software/MiniExcel/blob/master/README.md#2-ienumerableidictionarystring-object) but to me it seems like if I'm using a custom template file, I'm no longer able to have my Dynamic Columns setup...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey @Community I already provided ALL info I know... Sadly the thing I'm asking for doesn't have much coverage in documentations, and I couldn't find anything about it on Stackoverflow...